# Google Maps API - Is there any way to point to or indicate that there are markers out of view?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm loading stuff dynamically from an API, could be anywhere between 0 and 20 items. I load them without changing the users zoom, is there anyway to indicate that there are x number of markers in a certain direction?

I've seen before (not sure if with GoogleMaps or not) where they have an arrow that points to out of view markers. So as you shift your view, the pointers shift too, so not only do you know that there *are* markers, but exactly what direction they are in. That would be ideal, but any other solution would be helpful too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use the fitBounds() method, looks something like this.

```
   var markers = [];//some array
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
 bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```